# All subdomains as same-origin in referrer policy

Tags: javascript, referrer

My myapp is located on `myapp.department.institution.com`, while the company-wide login apps are on `login.department.institution.com` and `apps.institution.com`. Now we have an issue with the reduced-referrer-granularity flag in google chrome.

The myapp first redirects to login, which then redirects to apps. Apps in turn is supposed to redirect to login again, but with a full referrer url `https://apps.institution.com/?app=myapp`, but instead only sends `http://apps.institution.com/`.

If I disable the flag, it works fine. From my very limited knowledge about referrer policies, it seems that my only option is to set the referrer policy in apps.institution.com to "unsafe-url". Is there any way to make referrer policies in a way that all subdomains of the institution.com domain are considered same-origin?

I did find a tutorial explaining that you can bypass the strict rules (exact match) with the JS code

```
 document.domain = 'institution.com';
```

but it did not specify where I'd have to set this. Probably in apps.institution.com, right? Because that is something I do not have access to and which is linked to a massive amount of apps, so any changes there might be troublesome. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Hi @big_omegalul — did you ever figure out the best approach to this? Trying to solve a similar problem myself... thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Jack did you find any workaround for this , I stuck on this to allow my domain from my subdomain